# Click event on table cell in Angular

Tags: angular

So, I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to be able to log the number on the same column on the console, so, i used "(click)" event

```
(click)="onCellSelect(dayLoop)"
```

but, when i clicked, the console log out all of those 24 numbers.

[image]

Here's the full code

-file.HTML

```
        <div
            *ngFor="let facility of facilityList"

        >
            <div
                (click)="showEvent(facility.facility_id)"

            >
                <div

                >
                    <div>{{ facility.facility_name }}</div>
                    <div>{{ facility.facility_code || '' }}</div>
                    <div>
                        {{ facility.need_driver ? (facility.facility_default_driver_name || 'no_name' | translate) : '' }}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{ facility.need_driver ? (facility.facility_default_driver_phone || 'no_phone' | translate) : '' }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div></div>

            <div
                (click)="onCellSelect(dayLoop)"
                *ngFor="let day of facility.chart"

            >
                <div

                >
                    <div style="position: absolute;width: 100%; height: 100%;display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
                        <div

                            class="line"
                            *ngFor="let item of dayLoop"
                        ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            *ngFor="let item of day"
                            [ngStyle]="{
                                width: item.event_percent * 100 + '%',
                                'background-color': item.bg
                            }"
                        ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

+file.TS

```
}
onCellSelect(dayLoop, facility_id) {
    console.log(dayLoop)
}
```

Well, to sum it up, i want to click on a table cell, and display the corresponding number(hour) on the column.

Any tips to work on this ?

P.S: the table is being display on an Angular Dialog Material

Comment: P.S ignore the facility_id in the .ts file, i forgot to delete it

Comment: could you remove style to make the code more clear

Comment: You are passing dayLoop property as parameter that's why It's printing array of  value. Which is dayLoop property holding.

Comment: @HsuanLee Edited, does it help you understand the code better ?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I understand that, so, is there any way to tackle this problem. like retrive a data in the array

Comment: Is facilityList also same length as dayLoop?

Comment: @Chellappanவ no, the facilityList only have 4, that contain the name, phonenumber and and type of facility. And it doesn't really affect much about my current problem ,so...

Comment: I mean, you can get index of facility.chart or facilityList based on your loop and then pass that id to onCellSelect  method to get specific value

Comment: This question would really benefit from a live example. Can you create a stackblitz

Comment: Well, this is company's private stuffs, so this all i can able to show, sorry

Comment: You can create a mock example - a minimal reproducible example is all about recreating a problem using simple mock code.

Comment: You can create a stackblitz using the code you have posted, backed up by mock facility data.

Comment: again, i really wish i could, but i already violate the company's policy without them knowing already so, this is all i could